# Vue + Element UI: (el-select) create new option and then put an customized object into data

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

In Vue2 I got Two **el-select**.
One is for selecting count,the other one is for name,
when you select the name it will save both name and price to **data**

```
<el-select
   v-model="item"
   value-key="name"
 >
   <el-option
     v-for="(option,index) in OptionsArr"
     :key="index"
     :label="option.name"
     :value="option"
   >
    {{option.name}}
   </el-option>
```

**OptionsArr**

```
[
 {
  name: "apple" ,
  price: 200
 },
 {
  name: "orange" ,
  price: 150
 }
]
```

**initial data**

```
[
 {
  name:"",
  price:0,
  count:0
 }
]
```

**data when select apple**

```
[
 {
  name:"apple",
  price:200,
  count:0
 }
]
```

And now I want to let user create their own option so I add **filterable**, **allow-create** and **default-first-option** to this **el-select**

```
<el-select
   v-model="item"
   value-key="name"
   filterable
   allow-create
   default-first-option
```

Now when I input "NewOption" to create an option, it just add a string to the data array, the data becomes:

```
[
 "NewOption"
]
```

and I want to add a object to the array like this:

```
[
 {
  name:"NewOption",
  price:0,
  count:0
 }
]
```

I tried @change to put an object to the array, but in that way the other el-select which bind the count of the data item cannot work.

```
<el-select
 v-model="item.count"
```